# p:submenu is not expanded

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying but figure out how to use p:panelMenu

for some reason I am unable to make a submenu item expanded like the showcase example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelMenu.jsf

This is my jsf example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panelMenu style="width:300px"> 
            <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax Menuitem"> 
                <p:menuitem value="Delete"  ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-close" /> 
            </p:submenu>   
        </p:panelMenu> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: that's strange, its working for me. you are using primefaces 3.4 right ?? and make sure primefaces< 3.4 is not overriding in your worspace

Comment: Yes I am using 3.4 ,its probably something very stupid but I don’t know what it is :(
I will try to create a separate project

Comment: what do you mean by "overriding in your worspace" ?

Comment: i meant make sure you dont have any other primefaces jars included in your classpath except 3.4